# How to parse json key and arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have such a json data I want to parse in C#.

```
Json : 
   {
    Key1 : 5,
    Key2 : 6,
    Array : [
         {Id : 5} , 
         {Id : 6} , 
         {Id : 7} ,
         ...
    ]
    }
```

C# code:

```
var dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonData);
var key1 = dict["Key1"];
var key2 = dict["Key2"];
var array = dict["Array"];

// array type is object { System.Collections.ArrayList }
```

with this code I can take key1 and key2 values but I can't take Array values.
How can I parse Array values?

Comment: that's not json.  json quotes keys.

Answer (score 0):

use this methode to parse json string

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd use JSON.NET to deserialize the JSON into a JObject.  Then you can traverse the JSON object model which is easier than forcing it into a dictionary.

The equivalent parsing code looks like:

```
 var json = JObject.Parse(jsonData)
 JValue the_id_of_the_first_item_in_the_array_named_Array = ((JValue)json["Array"][0]["Id"]);
 object the_underlying_value = the_id_of_the_first_item_in_the_array_named_Array.Value;
```

Run it at .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mbmane

Answer (score 0):

using `dynamic` keyword can make your code more readable..

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

int key1 = obj.Key1;
int key2 = obj.Key2;
foreach(var item in obj.Array)
{
    int id = item.Id;
    Console.WriteLine(id);
}
```

PS: It requires [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)